# Unordered list containing list items with dynamic widths - horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, html-lists

I need help trying to space my horizontal menu the width of its parent `<div>`.

The problem is that the list items in the `<ul>` are dynamic, so there are a number of combinations varying depending on whether or not you are logged, whether or not you have joined the page, and whether or not you are an Admin.

I have set the `<ul>` to be `100%` of the parent `<div>`. This works fine. Currently my `<li>`s are all just left aligned, you can see this on http://www.daddyleagues.com/OzeSportsCFM (it's the section with home coaches stats etc)

The problem is that I am only editing this by using CSS overrides and JS (adding classes etc) through a CMS. I can't adjust the widths as the list is determined.

So I am wondering if there is any magical way to make the `<li>`s calculate their own `%`

I'm thinking I may just have to create some JavaScript function which adds the widths in `%` depending on what items appear. This is a last resort, hoping someone has some easier way.

Comment: have u seen justified navs in bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css3 [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

```
ul{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Read more about flexbox @ [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Flexbox browser support @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Good call for flexbox!
However, It's IE support is less than ideal: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Though we don't know his browser support needs, either.

Comment: Wow, awesome! So much better than the 60 line javascript function I wrote haha... I used justify-content: center as space-around but big ugly spaces between my lis, rather than actually making the lis wider... Is there any way to space out the lis and have no padding between them? http://i.imgur.com/gRMB7sQ.png

Answer (score 0):

get your list parent element (ul), lets call it "menu" for the sake of an answer.

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
    width = 100 / menu.length;

Array.prototype.slice.call(menu.children).forEach(function(li) {
  li.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + width + '%;');
});
```